# Rails - Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics-api

I am looking to implement Google Analytics Reporting API in our application and this is the flow i am looking to implement.

1. User clicks to Give our application access to Google Analytics API
2. User Logs in the Provides access to Google API
3. We fetch the Analytics Account
4. User Selects which Account he wants to attach to our service
5. Then we fetch details for this account

I am not able to figure out how to push users to allow the access. I tried using the Google Service Accounts but looks like it provides access to my accounts. How can i get access to the Users Google Analytics account?

Comment: You need to use Oauth2 if you want to access a users personal data.   Service accounts are preauthorized to accounts you the developer have access to.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks. is there a library google provides for Rails that can help us get started?

Comment: No idea there is one for ruby I just googled it https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client try googling around